# How to create sub-bucket aggregation on the basis of hierarchy field value (part of the field)

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming that we have a documents that has a hierarchy field like this:

```
POST subbuckets/_doc
{
  "hierarchy": "this/is/some/hierarchy"
}

POST subbuckets/_doc
{
  "hierarchy": "this/is/some/hierarchy2"
}

POST subbuckets/_doc
{
  "hierarchy": "this/is/another/hierarchy1"
}
```

I would like to count number of documents that belongs to **each** hierarchy level
I.e.

- `"this"` hierarchy level has 3 documents
- `"this/is"` hierarchy level has 3 documents
- `"this/is/some"` hierarchy level has 2 documents
- `"this/is/another"` hierarchy level has 1 document
- `"this/is/another/hierarchy1"` hierarchy level has 1 document
- `"this/is/some/hierarchy"` hierarchy level has 1 document
- `"this/is/some/hierarchy2"` hierarchy level has 1 document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not applied analyzer on `keyword` so to resolved this issue we have define field as `text` type and enable aggregation on `text` field and set `"fielddata": true`. Please check below configuration.

**Index Mapping:**

```json
PUT index5
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "path-analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "path-tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "path-tokenizer": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": "/"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "hierarchy": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "path-analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "keyword",
        "fielddata": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Documents**:

```json
POST index5/_doc
{
  "hierarchy": "this/is/some/hierarchy"
}

POST index5/_doc
{
  "hierarchy": "this/is/some/hierarchy2"
}

POST index5/_doc
{
  "hierarchy": "this/is/another/hierarchy1"
}
```

**Query:**

```json
POST index5/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "path": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "hierarchy"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

**Response:**

```json
{
 "aggregations" : {
    "path" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "this",
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : "this/is",
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : "this/is/some",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "this/is/another",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "this/is/another/hierarchy1",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "this/is/some/hierarchy",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "this/is/some/hierarchy2",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Checking on this, looks promising :)

Comment: @user18154574 sure. Please check and upvote and mark as solution if it helps you !!!

Comment: @SagarPatel, This is great ! Got to learn so much in one answer, Thanks!!